# Windows Terminal Server Standalone Security

Tags: windows, terminal-server

I have a Windows Server Terminal 2019 and its running as

- DC/DNS
- Terminal Server

Its running on a VM in the cloud and is reachable through public IP.
I dont want (cannot) build up a firewall in a second VM and build up a whole "network"....

I have configured Remote Desktop Gateway and using signed certificates.

I configured RD for RDWeb and its works. But how I close the "normal" rdp? Because How I understand Remote Dektop through RDWeb works no direct on port 3389 like the "Normal".

Or is it too "naive" and safety risk is to high?

Comment: "But how I close the "normal" rdp?" - put the server behind a firewall, such as any business should.

Comment: Voting to close: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: A domain controller acting as a terminal server is a recipe for disaster.
Exposing it to the Internet is just the icing on the cake.

Comment: I like cakes...
Okay. I will build up a own firewall...

Comment: @wulf The real issue here is that you shold not be using a DC as a terminal server; DCs should really not be used for anything else, but having users work on them is especially bad.

Comment: @Massimo Yeah I know. The Terminal Server is only for one applikation and its provided through RDWeb. So I think its not a high safety risk. They wont work via rdp on the maschine.

Comment: @Wulf it's still completely wrong. You need to be a domain admin to even *log on* to a DC, unless you lower the default security policies. The impact on security of treating a DC as a standard server is always high, quite often higher than expected.

Comment: @Massimo So it would be better to run two vm on a virtuell hyperv?

Comment: @Wulf this is not answerable without knowing much more about your environment. But please don't add more details here, ask another question if you need; this is quickly getting too broad.